# Class Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification does not exist

Tags: laravel, class, email

> Class Illuminate\Auth\Listeners\SendEmailVerificationNotification does
>   not exist

I am getting the above error whenever I try to use the `Mail:: send()`. I have set the mail detail in my `.env` file.

Here is my code

```
Mail::send('mail.newUserRegeration', $confirmation_code, function($message)
{
   $message->to(Input::get('email'))
   ->subject('Verify your email address');
});
```

I have used `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;`

Please point me out what am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you already succeeded to send emails anywhere else and are you sure you have installed authorization properly? It's a good point to start investigating from.

Comment: Yes, there was an ongoing project where I used Mail:send() but this Project I started from scratch. I have heard that if one did not set SMTP on server then it did not sent mail but then why do I get this error? And how can i send the mail from local server?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? This class only exists in the current **dev** version of Laravel (5.7).

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest version of laravel. I actually don't really know what this class is?